# Why does aspect-ratio: attr(width) / attr(height) not work on iframe

Tags: css, aspect-ratio

I read about this technique on CSS-Tricks and elsewhere, but it does not work on latest Brave or Firefox on Ubuntu 21.10.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) Firefox internal CSS supposedly is even using this. `aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;` works fine. What am I missing?

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  aspect-ratio: attr(width) / attr(height);
  /* aspect-ratio: 16 / 9; */ /* WORKS */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXx_Hw34V-Q" width="560" height="315">
</iframe>
```

Comment: On Chrome `aspect-ratio` is not supported even for images.

Comment: @Azu Where did you get that from? It's supported pretty much everywhere. https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio and it works when putting the numbers in directly as I have shown above.

Comment: Yes, I checked that site but on my local Chrome v96 it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do not make stuff up just because you think it does not work for you. AGAIN, manually defining it DOES work for the browsers I mentioned, and Brave is pretty much the same as Chrome. Latest Brave is build on Chromium 96... you just have no clue what you are doing. You probably do not have with and height: auto set that is needed for it.

Comment: it doesn't work on chrome either

Comment: the issue is not aspect ratio but the support of attr() outside the content property.